# how to use onError in copyRecursively in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, lambda, syntax

From https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/copy-recursively.html

```kotlin
fun File.copyRecursively(
    target: File,
    overwrite: Boolean = false,
    onError: (File, IOException) -> OnErrorAction = { _, exception -> throw exception }
): Boolean
```

How do you add the onError code and handle the exception?

I have the following code:

```kotlin
  val dest = File(filePath)
  source.copyRecursively(dest, true)
```

I do not know how to add the onError() to handle the exception

Comment: I would recommend taking a basic Kotlin tutorial, it will probably help you a lot more than answers here can! Specifically take a look at what a *lambda* is and how to use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either pass a lambda expression with the code, or a reference to an existing function.

Here is one way to pass a lambda:

```kotlin
val dest = File(filePath)
source.copyRecursively(dest, overwrite = true) { file, exception ->
    // do something with file or exception
    // the last expression must be of type OnErrorAction
}
```

Note that in Kotlin, if a function-type parameter is last, you can pass it outside of the parentheses like this.
If you want to show more explicitly that this is an error handler, you can do it by naming the argument, putting back into parentheses:

```kotlin
val dest = File(filePath)
source.copyRecursively(
    target = dest,
    overwrite = true,
    onError = { file, exception ->
        // do something with file or exception
        // the last expression must be of type OnErrorAction
    },
)
```

Comment: thanks! got confused with the OnErrorAction. Now I know it should be the return value as well.